# Select server using login screen password

Tags: java, database, android-studio, server, configuration

Background info:
My app currently has numerous build flavours for each client but this means I would have to add each APK to the play store which is not what I want. Ideally, I want to have one application for all clients which will launch a login screen, each client will have their own code which when entered will connect to their server.

I realise this is a broad question which is likely why my research isn't helping.

So, I'm asking for some guidance so I know what to research and know where to start.

Or in other words, what am I asking?

Comment: A centralized server to fetch the specific client properties which refer to the go-forward server?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use Firebase Remote Config? You can give parameters to your users and you can change some logic on client direct changing it on Firebase.